# Setting up Python in AMPPS - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, httpd.conf, internal-server-error

I'm trying to use Python with AMPPS, which is an Apache / MySQL / etc. bundle for Windows. There's just one problem though; every script I try to run returns an 'Internal Server Error', even though it's correct code.
This is probably an issue that's not worth posting it here, but I googled for three hours and I just can't find any help.

- My httpd.conf is over here: http://pastebin.com/5DMU2cUU
- The single line of code I use is: print "Hello World!";
- Notepad++ is set to EOL Conversion->UNIX format (before you ask).

This is all I know so far. Please don't hate me for posting this (I know you love to do that), I'm new and confused :3

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The syntax of `print` changed between v2 and v3.  http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, I just LoadModule'd the WSGI module that came with the bundle. (Changing the syntax didn't change anything though.)

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi is already configured in AMPPS. You can see it in loaded modules of apache.

```
httpd.exe -D DUMP_MODULES
```

You just need to configure your script now.
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

You can modify the **python.conf** included in **httpd.conf** too. i.e for using mod_wsgi directives.

This is official **hello world** example from mod_wsgi. Hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify, 'print "Hello World!";' alone is not a valid WSGI application. Go read the documentation and use the WSGI hello world in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Open httpd.conf
2. Append .py to AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl under  tag
   Now AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl  becomes AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
3. Search for block  and Add ExecCGI to Options FollowSymLinks Indexes. 
   Now its become Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
4. Save the httpd.conf file, stop the apache server and restart again.
   If the apache server restarts without any problem process you have successfully setup ampps to run python, otherwise restore the conf file from backup. In ampps there is an option to restore default configuration.
5. Add python exe file link line to the top of the python file to direct to the Python interpreter.It might be #!C:\Ampps\python\python.exe
6. Add this line print("Content-type: text/html\n")
7. Add this line print("Hello world!")
8. Now execute your python file. http://127.0.0.1/test/test.py
9. wsgi_module must be installed for apache to run python script via execCGI. On ampps this is installed and added to conf file by default.

link:http://www.lakshman.com.np/run-python-on-ampps-windows/